# Writing differential equation in Elliptic coordinate system

Tags: elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators

Consider below equation in an ellipsoid:

$\nabla^2 f(x,y) =  (1 + f(x,y))$

Knowing how to write this equation in polar coordinate with symmetries of a circle:

$\partial_r f(r)/r + \partial_r^2 f(r) = (1 + f(r))$

But I don't know in the case of an ellipse with elliptical symmetries, how can this equation be written. Could any one help? 
I know that laplacian in elliptical coordinate can be written as:

$\frac{(\partial_u^2+\partial_v^2)}{a^2(sinh^2 u + sin^2 v)}$

But I don't know how to apply symmetry of an ellipse to simplify it. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Just out of interest, how do $A$ and $b$ feature in the Laplacian?

Comment: There is no A and b. @Kevin

Comment: They were typo @Kevin

Comment: Is there any one in this cite who knows about elliptical coordinate?

Answer (score 1):

In elliptic coordinates ($a>0$ fixed, $u\geq0$ and $0\leq v\leq2\pi$), the equation $\nabla^2 f(x,y) =  (1 + f(x,y))$ can be written

$$\frac{1}{a^2(\sinh^2 u + \sin^2 v)}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2} + \frac{1}{a^2(\sinh^2 u + \sin^2 v)}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v^2} = 1 + f,$$

using the formula for the Laplacian in elliptic coordinates that you correctly identified.  This cannot be simplified for general $f=f(u,v)$, except in special cases such as $f=f(u)$, $f=f(v)$, or $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v^2} = 0$.

Comment: The main point of my question is writing laplacian in the special case with elliptical symmetry. I have written laplacian for a problem with circular symmetry as an example.

Comment: Hi @HolgerMate, to check if I understand correctly, are you asking what the equation will look like if we assume that $f$ is independent of the angular coordinate (i.e., if $f=f(u)$ or alternatively if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \equiv 0$)?

Comment: When is it useful to use elliptical coordinate system?

Comment: The main one that comes to my mind is when $\Omega$ (the domain on which your PDE is defined) is an ellipse or the exterior of an ellipse.  For example, $\Omega = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : (x/A)^2 + (x/B)^2 \leq 1 \}$ is an ellipse, and $\Omega = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : (x/A)^2 + (x/B)^2 \geq 1 \}$ is the exterior of an ellipse.

Comment: "when (the domain on which your PDE is defined) is an ellipse or the exterior of an ellipse" It is exactly my case in the question. I want to know how can this special domain simplify the laplace equation